# Can selecting a specific font/background color in your text editor enhance programmer productivity?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, ide

I have noticed that some developers prefer using blue or black backgounds in their respective ide's.

This might seem like a subjective question but when you are staring at source code for over 5 hours a day, surely you would like to choose a font/background color which would have the most positive effect on your day to day work.

So my question is, can selecting the correct font/background color enhance programmer productivity?

If it can which colors could be used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It certainly affects productivity, but there's no universal "correct" scheme.

What's "correct" is the scheme that the programmer selects for himself. For instance, I have worked with Phillipinos who prefer red on yellow. No way I can use such hues - but equally, those programmers would also question how I could work with my 'dull' colour scheme.

On the other hand, I learned that I have to keep backups of my own work that way. One of those programmers decided to jazz-up the screens I'd designed because he believed they were unusable. The users were most unhappy...

Imposing some variety of corporate standard is also likely to be disastrous. I spent a great deal of time modifying CLISTS to make ISPF basically green rather than blue (on a black background) - easier on the eyes. Most of my colleagues wanted a copy of my enhancements...

[OK - probably a lot of opinion here, but I'm certain that my productivity is lower when I'm forced to use someone else's colour scheme or layout]

Comment: Seems like color does have a negative/positive effect on a person, but it depends on your personality. Check out this website http://www.colour-affects.co.uk/the-colour-affects-system. Interesting stuff.